# SQL function not available when using code-first from database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I created a database in SQL Server Management Studio using the built in database (SQL Server LocalDB) when installing VS 2019 (`(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`).

I added a few tables > Add a function by Right clicking Functions under the Db and selecting "Inline table valued function". I created a simple function which executes when I type in

```
SELECT FunctionName()
```

In VS 2019, right-click the project > Add new item > ADO .Net Entity Data Model > code first from database.

I get to the screen below

[image]

but the import stored procedure and functions option is disabled.

Looked at the permissions but nothing is listed therefore added public and guest with `execute` permissions but these didn't work (so removed them).

The connection string I selected is using integrated security

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" 
         connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=CodeFirstTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I continued to select/add the tables and did a search for the function but I don't see it listed anywhere.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for Table Valued Functions in EF6 Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768124/support-for-table-valued-functions-in-ef6-code-first)

Comment: `SELECT FunctionName()` is the syntax you would use for a scalar-valued function, not a table-valued function. A TVF would also have "select" permissions, not "execute" permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! So i read that article and it seems its primarily a manual method and no way to get the Functions using the GUI?